# Zend Framework 3 Autocomplete form fields

Tags: forms, zend-framework3

After submitting the form, if there are errors they are displayed. If I refresh the page, the fields remain filled. The text of errors does not affect.

Help, how to avoid autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem. Nessesary to use **zend-mvc-plugin-prg**